# What is the most convenient way to stop an Ajax-object in prototype from swallowing exceptions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, exception, prototypejs

Consider this code:

```
new Ajax.Request('?service=example', {
    parameters : {tags : 'exceptions'},
    onSuccess : this.dataReceived.bind(this)
});
```

If an exception occurs anywhere in the dataReceived-function when it is called by the Ajax-object, it is swallowed by some exception handling code and the whole process then silently terminates. No exceptions are ever thrown to the browser and it is a bit tedious to debug (for understandable reasons). Is there any straightforward way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can include an `onException` callback handler with the request options:

```
new Ajax.Request('?service=example', {
  parameters : {tags : 'exceptions'},
  onSuccess : this.dataReceived.bind(this),
  onException : function(request, ex) { // react somehow }
});
```

To do it on a global level, the callback handler can be registered with the [`Ajax.Responders` object](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/responders):

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onException: function(request, ex) {
    // react somehow
  }
});
```

The first argument will be the `Ajax.Request` object that triggered the callback.

P.S./FYI: Your exception is being concealed by this code in the [Prototype source](http://www.prototypejs.org/assets/2009/3/27/prototype.js):

```
dispatchException: function(exception) {
  (this.options.onException || Prototype.emptyFunction)(this, exception);
  Ajax.Responders.dispatch('onException', this, exception);
}
```

Here's how to implement the onException callback correctly.

```
Ajax.Responders.register({ 
        onException: function(request, exception) { 
                (function() { throw exception; }).defer(); 
        } 
});
```

As documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2606239/147349

Comment: I knew of the onException parameter, but the Ajax.Responders.register-function was new to me. If I want all errors to spill to the browser during debugging this code would answer my needs: 

Ajax.Responders.register({ 
  onException: function(request, ex) { 
    if (debug) { throw ex; } 
  } 
}); 

Then i just need to set the debug flag to true to have all errors happening within code called from the Ajax-object thrown to the browser. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry. I', new here, so I didn't know the routine :)