# How to make javascript error console print out errors within callbacks?

Tags: javascript, firebug

If I have a javascript error *outside* of a callback, Firebug console prints out the error. However, if I have ant error *inside* a callback, I will not see any printout.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    // not notified in console
    alert(undefinedVariable);
});

// notified in console
alert(anotherUndefinedVariable);
```

Almost all of my code is inside callbacks, so it is making it hard for me to track down errors. How do I print out *every* error in the console no matter where the error occurs?

Comment: Since it seems you're using Prototype, could it be related to this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601411/prototype-callback-functions-swallowing-exceptions

Comment: Did you try the same code in Chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to tell Prototype to not swallow the exceptions.

```
Ajax.Responders.register({ 
        onException: function(request, exception) { 
                (function() { throw exception; }).defer(); 
        } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try printing to the console explicitly -- *window.console.log(...something...)* should work from anywhere.

Comment: I would like to be notified of errors automatically via the error console without having to manually `console` every variable in existence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here? whether you write "alert(...)" or "window.console.log(...)" are equivalent in the sense that you wrote that line, so if you don't want to write all those lines yourself, it doesn't matter what the lines is? As for automatic notification without writing any code: JavaScript engines only do this for things that throw, and consequently terminate-if-not-caught your script. So... can you better explain what you really want?

Comment: The alert was just an example. I want to print out all errors, regardless of whether it's alerted or not. For example, this line does not alert anything: `var foo = undefinedVar + 5`, but it should print an error to the console.

Comment: you'll want to rephrase your question then. This code, for instance, generates two errors, both of which show up in the various browser's debugging tools:

setTimeout(function(){alert(undefinedVariable);},1000); alert(anotherUndefinedVariable);

If you're seeing something else, create a demonstrator jsfiddle.net post and add it to your question as a demonstrator of what actually goes wrong.